# jQuery input selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

How would I initiate an function (in this case some ajax) when a user selects from an autocomplete text box (it uses jQuery UI).

EG User clicks into an input box, types 'A' this then resolves items with A in it using the autocomplete and once they select (click or press Enter) then do an event.

Comment: Read the docs for UI autocomplete. It's really quite straightforward :)

Comment: I assume you're using jQueryUI's Autocomplte, so use the [`select`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select) option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `select` callback. [From the docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select):

> Triggered when an item is selected from the menu; ui.item refers to the selected item. The default action of select is to replace the text field's value with the value of the selected item. Canceling this event prevents the value from being updated, but does not prevent the menu from closing.
>
> Code examples
>
> Supply a callback function to handle the select event as an init option.

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   select: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

> Bind to the select event by type: autocompleteselect.

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "autocompleteselect", function(event, ui) {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you should read the documentation with such a vague question. It's the best resource. http://docs.jquery.com/UI

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#element_id" ).autocomplete({
   select: function(event, ui) {
   var selected_value = $(this).val();
   // do something
   }
});
```